# Syncing a List between different sheets keeping properties sticked to a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

Maybe the title is not explicit enough, but what do I want to achieve, is:

1. I want to have a single place to edit a list (customers) with some metadata, to be used across the entire spreadsheet.
2. Some sheets may contain editable data as rows tied to the 1st column with the customer Ids. E.g. prices for services for each Customer for each month.

So, when I add an entry (Customer) to the 1st (master) sheet, it appears in the pricing table and doesn't break the existing entries (the rows remain connected).

So far I've not found any native solution for this. Should I look for extensions fo this, or code it using the app script?

Comment: there is no native solution to this.  it is very often asked about, but does not exist with native tools.

Comment: It seems VLOOKUP would be enough for the job

Comment: It's tricky as changes to the master list might trigger a jump in any subsequent sheets. I assume you could achieve this by being strict on not allowing rows to be entered manually and always referring to the row number in the master list. Difficult to be more specific without proper examples of problems you're facing.